# homestead.yaml file in .homestead and Homestead/src/stubs folder

Tags: laravel, yaml, homestead

My question is why is there a `homestead.yaml` file in `.homestead folder` and in the `Homestead/src/stubs folder`?

On my internship machine (Mac), I have been making changes to the `Homestead/src/stub` yaml file. On my home machine (Linux), it doesn't read those changes and I have to edit the `.homestead` yaml file instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `homestead.yml` file in `./Homestead/src/stubs` is there only as a placeholder before its copied to your home directory during installation. It should **not** be edited.

Only edit the file in  `~/.homestead`.

Make sure your ran the `bash init.sh` script on your Mac from the `./Homestead` directory.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#first-steps

Answer (score 0):

Though the Question has been answered but as it appeared while I was searching for homestead.YAML, It would be good to tell newbies that Homestead.YAML holds the whole configurations on windows and macs. It allows you to add sites, manage shared folders and much more. I will recommend this definitive guide for understanding homestead.yaml, The whole post is very long so I can't copy it

https://abbasharoon.me/homestead-yaml-explained-a-z/